# Performance of creating view postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I've built many queries on my PostgreSQL database, but some of them take a very long time to load, and I'm having trouble understanding why. Especially the one below, which can return a lot of information but uses very simple tables, so I don't understand the execution time. Could you help me understand why it's taking so long?
Thanks in advance!

query :

```
    explain(analyze, verbose, buffers) SELECT prj_projet.prj_spkprojet,
           prj_projet.prj_cintituleprojet,
           prj_projet.prj_spkprojet                              AS "Id",
           prj_projet.prj_cnumeroprojet,
           prj_projet.prj_bprojetmodele,
           prj_projet.prj_sfkcategorie,
           intervenants.prj_intervenant_projet,
           '[]'::jsonb                                           AS prj_utilisateur,
           prj_projet.prj_sfktype,
           prj_projet.prj_sfketat,
           prj_projet.prj_created_date                           AS prj_xcreated_date,
           prj_projet.prj_last_modified_date                     AS prj_xlast_modified_date,
           concat(utl1.utl_cnom, ' ', utl1.utl_cprenom)          AS prj_created_by,
           concat(utl2.utl_cnom, ' ', utl2.utl_cprenom)          AS prj_last_modified_by,
           grouprs.tmp_spkutilisateur,
           grouprs.tmp_spkutilisateur IS NULL                    AS tmp_butilisateur,
           doss.pjd_sfkdossier                                   AS prj_sfkdossier,
           (SELECT DISTINCT string_agg(encode(pg_largeobject_1.data, 'escape'::text), ''::text) AS string_agg
            FROM baseteamberv20prj.prj_projet prj1
                     JOIN pg_largeobject pg_largeobject_1 ON prj1.prj_cphoto = pg_largeobject_1.loid
            WHERE prj1.prj_spkprojet = prj_projet.prj_spkprojet) AS prj_cphoto,
           prj_projet.prj_sdesactive,
           prj_projet.prj_sfkinstance                            AS "Instance"
    FROM baseteamberv20prj.prj_projet
             LEFT JOIN (SELECT COALESCE(jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('itp_sfkintervenant', pi.int_sfkcontact,
                                                                              'itp_sfkintervenant_contrat',
                                                                              pi.int_spkintervenant, 'itp_sfktyperelation',
                                                                              prj_intervenant_projet.itp_sfktyperelation,
                                                                              'itp_sfktypeintervenant',
                                                                              prj_intervenant_projet.itp_sfktypeintervenant))
                                        FILTER (WHERE prj_intervenant_projet.itp_spkintervenantprojet IS NOT NULL),
                                        '[]'::jsonb) AS prj_intervenant_projet,
                               prj_intervenant_projet.itp_sfkprojet
                        FROM baseteamberv20prj.prj_intervenant_projet
                                 JOIN baseteamberv20prj.prj_intervenant pi
                                      ON prj_intervenant_projet.itp_sfkintervenant = pi.int_spkintervenant
                        GROUP BY prj_intervenant_projet.itp_sfkprojet) intervenants
                       ON intervenants.itp_sfkprojet = prj_projet.prj_spkprojet
             LEFT JOIN (SELECT COALESCE(jsonb_agg(ppud.pru_sfkutilisateur)
                                        FILTER (WHERE ppud.pru_spkprojetutilisateur IS NOT NULL),
                                        '[]'::jsonb) AS prj_utilisateur,
                               pj.prj_spkprojet
                        FROM baseteamberv20prj.prj_projet pj
                                 LEFT JOIN baseteamberv20prj.prj_projet_utilisateur ppud
                                           ON pj.prj_spkprojet = ppud.pru_sfkprojet AND ppud.pru_sfktyperelation  1
                        GROUP BY pj.prj_spkprojet) users ON users.prj_spkprojet = prj_projet.prj_spkprojet
             LEFT JOIN (SELECT mat_vutilisateur_groupe_projet.tmp_spkutilisateur,
                               mat_vutilisateur_groupe_projet.prj_spkprojet
                        FROM baseteamberv20prj.mat_vutilisateur_groupe_projet) grouprs
                       ON grouprs.prj_spkprojet = prj_projet.prj_spkprojet
             LEFT JOIN (SELECT prj_projet_dossier.pjd_sfkprojet,
                               prj_projet_dossier.pjd_sfkdossier
                        FROM baseteamberv20prj.prj_projet_dossier
                        LIMIT 1) doss ON doss.pjd_sfkprojet = prj_projet.prj_spkprojet
             LEFT JOIN baseteamberv20utl.utl_utilisateur utl1
                       ON prj_projet.prj_created_by = utl1.utl_spkutilisateur AND prj_projet.prj_sdesactive = 0
             LEFT JOIN baseteamberv20utl.utl_utilisateur utl2
                       ON prj_projet.prj_last_modified_by = utl2.utl_spkutilisateur AND prj_projet.prj_sdesactive = 0;
```

Plan :

```
    Hash Right Join  (cost=16173.72..5766871.09 rows=2224538 width=293) (actual time=1367.509..14853.652 rows=2224540 loops=1)
      Hash Cond: (mat_vutilisateur_groupe_projet.prj_spkprojet = prj_projet.prj_spkprojet)
      ->  Seq Scan on mat_vutilisateur_groupe_projet  (cost=0.00..36415.38 rows=2224538 width=16) (actual time=0.011..211.351 rows=2224538 loops=1)
      ->  Hash  (cost=15980.52..15980.52 rows=15456 width=176) (actual time=1367.413..1367.424 rows=15456 loops=1)
            Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 14575kB
            ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=13800.90..15980.52 rows=15456 width=176) (actual time=930.818..1349.884 rows=15456 loops=1)
                  Hash Cond: (prj_projet.prj_last_modified_by = utl2.utl_spkutilisateur)
                  Join Filter: (prj_projet.prj_sdesactive = 0)
                  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=13791.25..15930.29 rows=15456 width=170) (actual time=930.725..1347.195 rows=15456 loops=1)
                        Hash Cond: (prj_projet.prj_created_by = utl1.utl_spkutilisateur)
                        Join Filter: (prj_projet.prj_sdesactive = 0)
                        ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=13781.59..15879.04 rows=15456 width=164) (actual time=930.604..1343.656 rows=15456 loops=1)
                              Merge Cond: (prj_projet.prj_spkprojet = doss.pjd_sfkprojet)
                              ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=13781.54..15840.34 rows=15456 width=156) (actual time=930.566..1341.224 rows=15456 loops=1)
                                    Merge Cond: (prj_projet.prj_spkprojet = prj_intervenant_projet.itp_sfkprojet)
                                    ->  Index Scan using prj_projet_pkey on prj_projet  (cost=0.29..726.42 rows=15456 width=124) (actual time=807.998..814.038 rows=15456 loops=1)
                                          Filter: (prj_sdesactive = 0)
                                    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=13781.26..14734.72 rows=15136 width=40) (actual time=122.530..521.385 rows=15455 loops=1)
                                          Group Key: prj_intervenant_projet.itp_sfkprojet
                                          ->  Sort  (cost=13781.26..13972.32 rows=76426 width=48) (actual time=122.394..130.368 rows=76426 loops=1)
                                                Sort Key: prj_intervenant_projet.itp_sfkprojet
                                                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 9269kB
                                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=5562.54..7582.43 rows=76426 width=48) (actual time=57.770..93.160 rows=76426 loops=1)
                                                      Hash Cond: (prj_intervenant_projet.itp_sfkintervenant = pi.int_spkintervenant)
                                                      ->  Seq Scan on prj_intervenant_projet  (cost=0.00..1819.26 rows=76426 width=40) (actual time=0.016..6.338 rows=76426 loops=1)
                                                      ->  Hash  (cost=3727.24..3727.24 rows=146824 width=16) (actual time=57.156..57.157 rows=146824 loops=1)
                                                            Buckets: 262144  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8594kB
                                                            ->  Seq Scan on prj_intervenant pi  (cost=0.00..3727.24 rows=146824 width=16) (actual time=0.012..20.181 rows=146824 loops=1)
                              ->  Sort  (cost=0.05..0.05 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.027..0.029 rows=1 loops=1)
                                    Sort Key: doss.pjd_sfkprojet
                                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                                    ->  Subquery Scan on doss  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.023..0.024 rows=1 loops=1)
                                          ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.019..0.020 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                ->  Seq Scan on prj_projet_dossier  (cost=0.00..1.59 rows=59 width=16) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=1 loops=1)
                        ->  Hash  (cost=7.07..7.07 rows=207 width=22) (actual time=0.102..0.103 rows=207 loops=1)
                              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 20kB
                              ->  Seq Scan on utl_utilisateur utl1  (cost=0.00..7.07 rows=207 width=22) (actual time=0.010..0.055 rows=207 loops=1)
                  ->  Hash  (cost=7.07..7.07 rows=207 width=22) (actual time=0.078..0.078 rows=207 loops=1)
                        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 20kB
                        ->  Seq Scan on utl_utilisateur utl2  (cost=0.00..7.07 rows=207 width=22) (actual time=0.007..0.033 rows=207 loops=1)
      SubPlan 1
        ->  Unique  (cost=2.54..2.55 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=2224540)
              ->  Sort  (cost=2.54..2.55 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=2224540)
                    Sort Key: (string_agg(encode(pg_largeobject_1.data, 'escape'::text), ''::text))
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                    ->  Aggregate  (cost=2.52..2.53 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=2224540)
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..2.52 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=2224540)
                                Join Filter: (prj1.prj_cphoto = pg_largeobject_1.loid)
                                ->  Index Scan using prj_projet_pkey on prj_projet prj1  (cost=0.29..2.50 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=2224540)
                                      Index Cond: (prj_spkprojet = prj_projet.prj_spkprojet)
                                ->  Seq Scan on pg_largeobject pg_largeobject_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=2224540)
    Planning Time: 1.221 ms
    JIT:
      Functions: 72
      Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
      Timing: Generation 4.198 ms, Inlining 23.852 ms, Optimization 489.658 ms, Emission 294.622 ms, Total 812.330 ms
    Execution Time: 14968.105 ms
```

and even more shocking is that query really simple but took too long too..

Query :

```
    explain(analyze, verbose, buffers) SELECT prj_projet.prj_spkprojet,
               utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkutilisateur         AS tmp_spkutilisateur,
               utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkutilisateur IS NULL AS tmp_butilisateur
        FROM baseteamberv20prj.prj_projet
                 LEFT JOIN baseteamberv20prj.prj_projet_group ON prj_projet.prj_spkprojet = prj_projet_group.rpg_sfkprojet
                 LEFT JOIN baseteamberv20utl.utl_utilisateur_groupe
                           ON utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkgroupe = prj_projet_group.rpg_sfkgroupe AND
                              (utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkdroits = 56 OR utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkdroits = 57)
                 JOIN baseteamberv20utl.utl_utilisateur
                      ON utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkutilisateur = utl_utilisateur.utl_spkutilisateur AND
                         utl_utilisateur.utl_sdesactive = 0
        GROUP BY prj_projet.prj_spkprojet, utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkutilisateur;
```

Plan:

```
        HashAggregate  (cost=148677.79..180671.71 rows=3199392 width=17) (actual time=4746.171..5335.106 rows=2224538 loops=1)
      Output: prj_projet.prj_spkprojet, utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkutilisateur, (utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkutilisateur IS NULL)
      Group Key: prj_projet.prj_spkprojet, utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkutilisateur
      Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 204817kB
      Buffers: shared hit=5485 read=308
      ->  Hash Join  (cost=475.69..111410.49 rows=7453461 width=16) (actual time=26.440..2633.307 rows=5262632 loops=1)
            Output: prj_projet.prj_spkprojet, utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkutilisateur
            Inner Unique: true
            Hash Cond: (prj_projet_group.rpg_sfkprojet = prj_projet.prj_spkprojet)
            Buffers: shared hit=5485 read=308
            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.86..91364.97 rows=7453461 width=16) (actual time=21.612..1375.266 rows=5262632 loops=1)
                  Output: prj_projet_group.rpg_sfkprojet, utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkutilisateur
                  Buffers: shared hit=5440 read=308
                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..138.76 rows=1442 width=16) (actual time=21.555..28.826 rows=1560 loops=1)
                        Output: utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkutilisateur, utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkgroupe
                        Inner Unique: true
                        Buffers: shared hit=780
                        ->  Index Scan using fk02_utilisateur_groupe_idx on baseteamberv20utl.utl_utilisateur_groupe  (cost=0.28..67.44 rows=1442 width=16) (actual time=21.496..24.754 rows=1560 loops=1)
                              Output: utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_spkutilisateurgroupe, utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkinstance, utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkdroits, utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkfonction, utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkgroupe, utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkutilisateur, utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sdesactive, utl_utilisateur_groupe.created_by, utl_utilisateur_groupe.created_date, utl_utilisateur_groupe.last_modified_by, utl_utilisateur_groupe.last_modified_date
                              Filter: ((utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkdroits = 56) OR (utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkdroits = 57))
                              Rows Removed by Filter: 314
                              Buffers: shared hit=366
                        ->  Memoize  (cost=0.15..0.18 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1560)
                              Output: utl_utilisateur.utl_spkutilisateur
                              Cache Key: utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkutilisateur
                              Cache Mode: logical
                              Hits: 1353  Misses: 207  Evictions: 0  Overflows: 0  Memory Usage: 23kB
                              Buffers: shared hit=414
                              ->  Index Scan using utl_utilisateur_pkey on baseteamberv20utl.utl_utilisateur  (cost=0.14..0.17 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=207)
                                    Output: utl_utilisateur.utl_spkutilisateur
                                    Index Cond: (utl_utilisateur.utl_spkutilisateur = utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkutilisateur)
                                    Filter: (utl_utilisateur.utl_sdesactive = 0)
                                    Buffers: shared hit=414
                  ->  Memoize  (cost=0.43..87.29 rows=4693 width=16) (actual time=0.002..0.378 rows=3373 loops=1560)
                        Output: prj_projet_group.rpg_sfkprojet, prj_projet_group.rpg_sfkgroupe
                        Cache Key: utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkgroupe
                        Cache Mode: logical
                        Hits: 1490  Misses: 70  Evictions: 0  Overflows: 0  Memory Usage: 16439kB
                        Buffers: shared hit=4660 read=308
                        ->  Index Scan using fk02_projet_group_idx on baseteamberv20prj.prj_projet_group  (cost=0.42..87.28 rows=4693 width=16) (actual time=0.043..2.152 rows=5008 loops=70)
                              Output: prj_projet_group.rpg_sfkprojet, prj_projet_group.rpg_sfkgroupe
                              Index Cond: (prj_projet_group.rpg_sfkgroupe = utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkgroupe)
                              Buffers: shared hit=4660 read=308
            ->  Hash  (cost=281.63..281.63 rows=15456 width=8) (actual time=4.797..4.799 rows=15456 loops=1)
                  Output: prj_projet.prj_spkprojet
                  Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 732kB
                  Buffers: shared hit=45
                  ->  Index Only Scan using prj_projet_pkey on baseteamberv20prj.prj_projet  (cost=0.29..281.63 rows=15456 width=8) (actual time=0.019..1.995 rows=15456 loops=1)
                        Output: prj_projet.prj_spkprojet
                        Heap Fetches: 0
                        Buffers: shared hit=45
    Query Identifier: -964312065641516586
    Planning:
      Buffers: shared hit=484
    Planning Time: 3.152 ms
    JIT:
      Functions: 35
      Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
      Timing: Generation 2.191 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 1.139 ms, Emission 20.393 ms, Total 23.723 ms
    Execution Time: 5568.282 ms
```

Pour les DDL de projet :

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table prj_projet
(
    prj_spkprojet           bigserial
        primary key,
    prj_created_by          bigint,
    prj_created_date        timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    prj_last_modified_by    bigint,
    prj_last_modified_date  timestamp,
    prj_bpourproduction     boolean,
    prj_bprojetmodele       boolean,
    prj_cdescription        text,
    prj_cintitulelongprojet varchar(255),
    prj_cintituleprojet     varchar(255)                        not null,
    prj_cnumeroprojet       varchar(255),
    prj_cphoto              oid,
    prj_davancement         numeric(19, 2),
    prj_sdesactive          integer   default 0,
    prj_sfketat             bigint,
    prj_sfktype             bigint,
    prj_sfkinstance         integer,
    prj_sfkcategorie        bigint                              not null
        constraint fkqptq3ipqfp4p73y5dh3mto5ai
            references prj_projet_categorie,
    prj_sniddrupal          varchar(255)
);

alter table prj_projet
    owner to wandeed;

create index fk01_projet_idx
    on prj_projet (prj_sfktype);

create index fk02_projet_idx
    on prj_projet (prj_sfkcategorie);
```

sanchant qu'on ne voit pas ici (je ne sais pas pourquoi) l'index sur la clé primaire alors quelle est bien présente comme le montre la capture ci-dessous:
[image]

Pour les DDL de projet groupe :

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table prj_projet_group
(
    rpg_spkprojetgroupe    bigserial
        primary key,
    rpg_created_by         bigint,
    rpg_created_date       timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    rpg_last_modified_by   bigint,
    rpg_last_modified_date timestamp,
    rpg_sdesactive         integer   default 0,
    rpg_sfkgroupe          bigint,
    rpg_sfkinstance        integer,
    rpg_sfkrole            bigint,
    rpg_sfktyperelation    bigint                              not null,
    rpg_sfkprojet          bigint                              not null
        constraint fkov3jcw2mnaovo28nfaf8166wq
            references prj_projet
);

alter table prj_projet_group
    owner to wandeed;

create index fk01_projet_group_idx
    on prj_projet_group (rpg_sfkprojet);

create index fk02_projet_group_idx
    on prj_projet_group (rpg_sfkgroupe);

create index fk03_projet_group_idx
    on prj_projet_group (rpg_sfktyperelation);

create index prj_projet_group_rpg_sfkprojet_rpg_sfkgroupe_idx
    on prj_projet_group (rpg_sfkprojet, rpg_sfkgroupe)
    where ((rpg_sfktyperelation = 650) AND (rpg_sdesactive = 0));
```

Pour les DDL de utilisateur groupe :

```
create table utl_utilisateur_groupe
(
    ugr_spkutilisateurgroupe bigint  default nextval('baseteamberv20utl.ugr_spkutilisateurgroupe_seq'::regclass) not null
        primary key,
    ugr_sfkinstance          integer default 1                                                                   not null,
    ugr_sfkdroits            bigint,
    ugr_sfkfonction          bigint,
    ugr_sfkgroupe            bigint,
    ugr_sfkutilisateur       bigint
        constraint utl_utilisateur_groupe_fk
            references utl_utilisateur,
    ugr_sdesactive           integer default 0                                                                   not null,
    created_by               bigint,
    created_date             timestamp,
    last_modified_by         bigint,
    last_modified_date       timestamp,
    constraint unique_user_group
        unique (ugr_sfkdroits, ugr_sfkgroupe, ugr_sfkutilisateur, ugr_sfkfonction)
);

alter table utl_utilisateur_groupe
    owner to wandeed;

create index fk01_utilisateur_groupe_idx
    on utl_utilisateur_groupe (ugr_sfkutilisateur);

create index fk02_utilisateur_groupe_idx
    on utl_utilisateur_groupe (ugr_sfkgroupe);

create index fk03_utilisateur_groupe_idx
    on utl_utilisateur_groupe (ugr_sfkdroits);

create index groupe_utilisateur
    on utl_utilisateur_groupe (ugr_sfkgroupe, ugr_sfkutilisateur)
    where ((ugr_sdesactive = 0) AND ((ugr_sfkdroits = 56) OR (ugr_sfkdroits = 57)));
```

Comment: Could you please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for these statements and the DDL for all tables and indexes involved?

Comment: Thanks to your help ! i complete my question with ddl and you can find complete explain (replace into this)

Comment: What does this have to do with creating a view?

Answer (score 0):

`prj_projet.prj_spkprojet` is causing both slow times, check the index:

In the first, most time is spent in this index scan

```
     ->  Index Scan using prj_projet_pkey on prj_projet  (cost=0.29..726.42 rows=15456 width=124) (actual time=807.998..814.038 rows=15456 loops=1)
              Filter: (prj_sdesactive = 0)
```

In the second, most time is spent aggregating with this same field as group key.

```
HashAggregate  (cost=148607.53..180601.45 rows=3199392 width=17) (actual time=4204.896..4774.775 rows=2224538 loops=1)
      Group Key: prj_projet.prj_spkprojet, utl_utilisateur_groupe.ugr_sfkutilisateur
      Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 204817kB
```

Check the index, and if that doesn't lead to results, please come back with the DDL of the table/indexes.

Comment: I Post my index into this post but i don't understand why this index take too long because it's primary key of project table.. I also put DDL of 3 tables to see

Answer (score 0):

(Looking only at the first query)

The correlated subquery is executed in retail, and doing any subquery over 2 million times is going to be slow, even if each execution is rather fast.  This only explains about half the total execution time (0.004ms * 2224540 = 9s out of 15s) but the remaining half of the time is completely mysterious based on your plan.  It could be due to the overhead of calling the clock function a huge number of times--to test that theory you could try EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, TIMING OFF) and see if the total execution time drops.

To optimize, you could try calculating the subquery for every prj_spkprojet in bulk, and then join the rest of the query to that result:

```
SELECT ...., t.string_agg
.... LEFT JOIN
(SELECT prj_spkprojet, string_agg(encode(pg_largeobject_1.data, 'escape'::text), ''::text) AS string_agg
   FROM baseteamberv20prj.prj_projet prj1
   JOIN pg_largeobject pg_largeobject_1 ON prj1.prj_cphoto = pg_largeobject_1.loid
   group by prj_spkprojet
) t on t.prj_spkprojet = prj_projet.prj_spkprojet
....
```

Of course if pg_largeobject is always empty as it was in your demo, then this whole subquery is pointless in the first place.

Maybe the planner could be a bit smarter about doing this transformation for you, but as of now it is not.

I would also turn JIT off.  The time (visibly) spent doing it is not large, but is almost surely wasted, and it introduces a lot of complexity (and potential for bugs) for little potential gain.